# In a HIVE insert query why from clause is in the beginning?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I found this example and several others in o'reilly programmin hive:

```
FROM staged_employees se
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/or_employees'
SELECT * WHERE se.cty = 'US' and se.st = 'OR'
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/ca_employees'
SELECT * WHERE se.cty = 'US' and se.st = 'CA'
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/il_employees'
SELECT * WHERE se.cty = 'US' and se.st = 'IL';
```

I wonder why is it that 'from' clause in s in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

"FROM" clause is used at the beginning of the hive query for inserting data from a single table into multiple tables/directories. There is no need to write the table name in every select statement you use in the insert query. In the above query you mentioned, you can see that the "FROM" clause is missing in the select statements in the INSERT queries (for ex : SELECT * *missing FROM clause* WHERE se.cty = 'US' and se.st = 'OR').

This is useful when you want to insert data into several tables or directories in one go by selecting data from a single table. The table from which the data is being selected is written at the beginning of the query using FROM clause (FROM staged_employees se) which avoids writing it in all the insert queries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is a multi table insertion. Multiple tales or directories are updated in one go.
In the example you pointed out, the output of the query: 
SELECT * FROM stage_employees se WHERE se.cty = 'US' and se.st = 'OR'
is inserted to the table "/tmp/or_employees".

Same is the case with other two SELECT queries below where st = 'CA' and st = 'IL'.

Hope that helps
Prasanth